Used to get a nice plot, but now I get an empty plot with the same command
sometimes I am puzzled by Mathematica. What usually worked, and I Have double-checked, now gives an empty plot. Can someone test if they also get a blank plot?
Thanks
(* Define parameters *)
L = 10;                 (* Length of the domain *)
T = 15;                  (* Total time *)
dx = 0.08;               (* Spatial step size *)
dt = 0.001;             (* Time step size *)
xMax = L;               (* Maximum x value *)
xValues = Range[-L/2, L/2, dx]; (* Spatial grid *)
mMax = Round[T/dt];     (* Maximum time index *)

(* Peregrine soliton initial condition *)
\[Psi]0[x_] := (1 - 4 (1 + 2 I x)/(1 + 4 x^2)) Exp[I x];

(* Initialize wave function *)
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]0[x], {x, xValues}];

(* Define the time evolution function *)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := Module[{\[Psi]New, nonlinearTerm},
    \[Psi]New = \[Psi];  (* Start with the current wave function *)
    (* Update wave function using FDM *)
    For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++,
        nonlinearTerm = Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2 \[Psi][[i]];
        \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - dt nonlinearTerm;
    ];
    \[Psi]New
];

(* Store results for animation *)
results = {};
(* Time-stepping loop *)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++,
    \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
    If[Mod[m, Round[mMax/5]] == 0, AppendTo[results, \[Psi]]];  (* Store every 5th wave function *)
];

(* Create the animation *)
ListAnimate[Table[
  ListLinePlot[results[[m]], PlotRange -> All, 
               PlotLabel -> "Peregrine Soliton Evolution", 
               AxesLabel -> {"x", "|\[Psi](x,t)|^2"}, 
               PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
               ImageSize -> Large,
               PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}],
  {m, 1, Length[results]}
]]


If you look at your data, say results[[1]] you will see complex numbers.  So you add Abs or Re or Im then plot will show.  All what you had to do is just look at the data generated by your code :)  If this used to work before as is, then you must have changed something to make the result become complex. I do not think Mathematica will do it by itself.
